# Instantiating a python class from within the same class definition

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

```
from collections import defaultdict 

#This class represents a directed graph using adjacency list representation 
class Graph: 
    def __init__(self,vertices): 
        self.V= vertices #No. of vertices 
        self.graph = defaultdict(list) # default dictionary to store graph 

    # function to add an edge to graph 
    def addEdge(self,u,v): 
        self.graph[u].append(v) 

    # Function that returns reverse (or transpose) of this graph 
    def getTranspose(self): 
        g = Graph(self.V) 

        # Recur for all the vertices adjacent to this vertex 
        for i in self.graph: 
            for j in self.graph[i]: 
                g.addEdge(j,i) 
        return g 

g = Graph(5)
g.addEdge(1, 0)
g.addEdge(0, 2)
g.addEdge(2, 1) 
g.addEdge(0, 3) 
g.addEdge(3, 4)
```

The above code seems to work fine, but I am confused how can the class instantiation in getTranspose be done from within the same class?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be possible to create an instance of a class from inside of a method of that class? It's not like classes and methods are physical objects that need to physically fit into each other.

Comment: This I guess should not be allowed since, creating an instance of a class from within the same class can have an endless cycle?
Would something like this also be okay ?

class Graph:
    def __init__(self):
        g = Graph()

Comment: This whole concept of "inside" is very strange. You understand that code and objects are two entirely different things, right? An object can't really be "inside" a function. And the function isn't exactly "inside" the class, either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because all the information to create an object of a class (i.e., its members and the amount of memory the require) is already known at the point when you call one of its methods (in this case `getTranspose`).

If, however, you try to create an instance of the class in its own constructor, it will result in infinite recursion.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = A()  # This will lead to RecursionError being thrown
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because when you call the class Graph in your method, it's like calling the Graph constructor (the **init** method) with all its attributes, and since they all already declared, there's no reason why it shouldn't work
I had the same issue once, but my programming teacher told me this and it makes sense